# windows 10 bash home dictionary redirect

Tags: windows, bash, authentication, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed the bash on windows 10, but when I login by using bash, the home dictionary has been redirected to the home of windows(/mnt/c/Users/haidescs) not the correct bash home(~).
See the screenshot.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCpA7.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go directly to your WSL home directory: type:   bash ~

Answer (score 0):

Your bash home directory (i.e `~`) is still set at `/home/haidescs`. When you run bash.exe from the Command Prompt, it opens bash in Command Prompt's current directory. For example, if you run bash from `C:\`, the bash current directory will be the same (`/mnt/c`):

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\username>cd C:\

C:\>bash
username@AMP:/mnt/c$ pwd
/mnt/c
```

Answer (score 0):

Try typing

```
cd
```

from the bash prompt and see where that takes you. It should take you to your actual home folder. As someone mentioned already, bash will open in the same directory you are when you launch it from the command prompt.